# How to calculate the shortest distance between $x^2$ and $2x-6$

Tags: calculus, geometry

So my question is how to calculate the shortest distance between the curves $y=x^2$ and $g=2x-6$?

I tried doing the following myself:

$$\Delta z (x_0,x_1) = \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}=\sqrt{\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2+\left(x_0^2-2x_1+6\right)^2}$$

Now by calculating the gradient of $\Delta z$ and equating it to $0$ we should get the optimal point, right? But this calculation got really meassy for me with 3rd degree terms etc. Is this the way to go for it? or is there an easier way?

Comment: when the slope of a tangent to $x^2$ is equal to the slope of $g$. slope of the shortest line will be $-1/2$,

Comment: Thank you @Vikram excellent! =)

Comment: @Vikram Just check first that the two curves don't cross.

Comment: Check that $x^2-(2x-6)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then use what @Vikram says, that's best approach to deal this sort of problems.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to find the minimum of $(\Delta z(x_0,x_1))^2$, that way you avoid the square roots. The function becomes

$$(x_1-x_0)^2 + (x_0^2 - 2x_1 + 6)^2 =\\= x_1^2 + x_0^2 - 2x_0x_1 + x_0^4 + 4x_1^2 + 36 - 4x_0^2x_1  + 12x_0^2 - 24x_1$$

Which you can first simplify, then find the zeroes of the derivatives.

Comment: Thank you for your help! =)

Comment: by the way, I think there should be (-) somewhere in place of (+) in your answer =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi You are correct. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to minimize the function $\Delta z^2$; this function has the same Minimum Points as the square root of this function.

Assuming that at a Point $x_0$ the "y-value" is $y(x_0)$ and at a Point $x_1$ the "y-value" is $g(x_1)$. Then you have $\Delta z^2 = \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 = (x_1-x_0)^2+(g(x_1)-y(x_0))^2$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $x^2=2x-6$ has no real solutions hence there is no intersection. Now assume that $A=(x_0,x_0^2)$ is the point on $y=x^2$ which has the minimum distance from $g=2x-6$ at point $B=(x_1,2x_1-6)$. Note that For $AB$ segment to have a minimum length, it should be perpendicular to both $y=x^2$ and $g=2x-6$ hence the line connecting $A$ and $B$ has a slope of $-\frac12$. Therefore $y'=2x$ equals $2$ at $A$. Hence $A=(1,1)$. And the locus of line $AB$ is $y=-\frac12 x+\frac{3}{2}$. Therefore $-\frac12 x+\frac{3}{2}=2x-6$ implies that $x_1=3$ and hence $B=(3,0)$. Hence the min distance is $$\sqrt{(1-3)^2+(1-0)^2}=\sqrt{5}.$$

Comment: You meant "And the locus of line AB is $y = -(1/2)x \textbf{+} 3/2$" (i.e., plus, not minus), which leads to the correct minimum distance, $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: ups, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your answers!

I think I got it myself also (after the help ;) ):

I know that the shortest distance between the curves $x^2$ and $2x-6$ is achieved by the straight line which is perpendicular to the tangents of both curves. This means that the derivatives of the two curves must be equal when this line "touches" the curves $x^2$ and $2x-6$. This happens when:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\right)=2x=2=\frac{d}{dx}\left(2x-6\right).$$

This means that $x_0=1$. Now the shortest distance between the two curves is achieved by minimizing the quantity:

$$(\Delta z)^2=Z=\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2+\left(x_0^2-2x_1+6\right)^2$$

Because $x_0=1$ we get

$$Z=\left(x_1-1\right)^2+\left(7-2x_1\right)^2$$

Now by taking the partial derivative with respect to $x_1$ and equation to $0$ we get:

$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_1}=2x_1-2-28+8x_1=0$$

$$10x_1=30$$

$$x_1=3$$

So the minimum distance is:

$$\Delta z =\sqrt{(3-1)^2+(1-0)^2}=\sqrt{5}$$